# How to differentiate data types in a subroutine?

Tags: java

My assignment goes as follows:

> Write subroutines to find the smallest of two values using an overloaded function.
>
> ```
> int smallest (int a, int b)
> char smallest (char a, char b)
> float smallest (float a, float b)
> double smallest (double a, double b)
> ```

I have to use the `Scanner` class for input and have the same code in all of the subroutines. My problem is listed after the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package subassignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subassignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

        String a, b;
        int v1, v2, min;

        System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
        a = console.next();
        System.out.println("Enter another value: ");
        b = console.next();

        v1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
        v2 = Integer.parseInt(b);         
        min = larger(v1, v2);

        System.out.println(min);

    }
    public static int larger(int x, int y){
        if (x > y){
           return y;
        }
        else{
           return x;   
        }
    }
public static char larger(char x, char y){
    if (x > y){
      return y;
    }
    else{
      return x;   
    }
 }
public static float larger(float x, float y){
    if (x > y){
       return y;
    }
    else{
      return x;   
    }
}
public static double larger(double x, double y){
    if (x > y){
      return y;
    }
    else{
     return x;   
    }  
 }
}
```

The program only works when I enter integer values. I thought that no matter what data type I entered `Integer.parseInt(a)` would convert it to an integer value. Where should I go to be able to enter values for `float`, `double`, and `char`.
Suppose my input is `g` and then `f`, I get this message in the compiler:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "g"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at subassignment.Subassignment.main(Subassignment.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

*Revision #2 after answer

```
package subassignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subassignment {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

        String a, b;
        int i1, i2, i3, type;
        char c1, c2, c3;
        double d1, d2, d3;
        float f1, f2, f3;

        System.out.println("What is your data type: ");
        System.out.println("1 for int: 2 for char: 3 for double: 4 for float ");
        type = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
        a = console.next();
        System.out.println("Enter another value: ");
        b = console.next();

        switch (type){
        case 1:{
        i1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
        i2 = Integer.parseInt(b);         
        i3 = larger(i1, i2);
        System.out.println(i3);
        break;
        }
        case 2:{
        c1 = a.charAt(0);
        c2 = b.charAt(0);
        c3 = larger(c1, c2);
        System.out.println(c3);
        break;
        }        
        case 3:{
        d1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
        d2 = Double.parseDouble(b);
        d3 = larger(d1, d2);
        System.out.println(d3);
        break;
        }
        case 4:{
        f1 = Float.parseFloat(a);
        f2 = Float.parseFloat(b);
        f3 = larger(f1, f2);
        System.out.println(f3);
        break;
        }
      }
    }
    public static int larger(int x, int y){
    if (x > y){
    return y;
        }
    else{
     return x;   
        }
    }
public static char larger(char x, char y){
if (x > y){
    return y;
   }
    else{
     return x;   
        }
    }
public static float larger(float x, float y){
if (x > y){
    return y;
   }
    else{
     return x;   
        }
    }
public static double larger(double x, double y){
if (x > y){
    return y;
   }
    else{
     return x;   
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(a);` tries to interpret `a` as an `Integer` and `"g"` is not..

Comment: You must first check wether your input is a digit or a char, before calling the larger method.

Comment: Where does your overloaded function fit with this? You're converting everything to an Integer.. or at least trying to. Also, you could try console.nextInt(), although it still needs to be a valid number.

Comment: Does your teacher really use the term _subroutine_? That's too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    You can scan one more input value and get the code working as below:-
    ......
.........
            System.out.println("Enter a Input Type Integer->1 :: Char->2 :: Float->3::Double->4 ");
    int inputType = console.next();
    System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
    a = console.next();
    System.out.println("Enter another value: ");
    b = console.next();
    int v1,v2,v3;
    char vc1,vc2,vc3;
    float vf1,vf2,vf3;
    double vd1,vd2,vd3;
    switch(inputType)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        v1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
        v2 = Integer.parseInt(b);
        v3=larger(v1,v2);
    }
    case 2:
    {
        vc1 = a.charAt(0);
        vc2 = b.charAt(0);
        vc3=larger(vc1,vc2);
    }
    case 3:
    {
        vf1 = Float.parseFloat(a);
        vf2= Float.parseFloat(b);
        vf3=larger(vf1,vf2);
    }
    case 4:
    {
        vd1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
        vd2 = Double.parseDouble(a);
        vd3=larger(vd1,vd2);
    }
    }
......
.......
```

Comment: Okay I used the switch statement and I got it to work. Thank you so much Tathagat. My only other thing is that I had to use break after the cases so they wouldn't continue to run through the loop. Is there a way to do this without the break statements as my professor will not accept anything with break statements. *The code had been revised above underneath the previous code.

Comment: I think regex will be better way to validate. Please see my comments below

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(String a) will work only for String to int conversion and hence not working for float, double or char input!!!

Comment: So I would have to write separate lines in the main part for each different data type? Such as if else statements(if a is an int, else if a is a double, etc...)?

Comment: you can scan one more parameter as input type and fix this issue as below:-

Comment: I do not think I am allowed to prompt the user to choose which data type. I was under the assumption that the computer had to differentiate between the users input.

Comment: Issue lies with String to int,float, char and double conversion along with storing int, float, char and double to proper datatype. you can use next solution provided by me.

Comment: You can use String.matches(String regex) to determine if input value is Int, char, float or double like as below:- if(a.matches("[A-Za-z]"))
   {
    System.out.println(a+" is char");
   } 
   else if(a.matches("[0-9]"))
   {
    System.out.println(a+" is integer");
   }
   else if(c.contains("."))
   {
    //Use some better way to match double 
    System.out.println(c+" is double");
   
   }
   else{
    //code for float matching
   }